# Ошибка Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Не получается настроить `references` в MySQL, не понимаю что делаю не правильно

Orders

```
 'use strict';
        module.exports = {
          up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.createTable('Orders', {
              id: {
                type: Sequelize.CHAR
              },
              storeId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: {
                  model: 'Stores',
                  key: 'id'
                }
              },
              createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
              },
              updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
              }
            });
          },
          down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.dropTable('Orders');
          }
        };
```

Store

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Stores', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      login: {
        type: Sequelize.CHAR
      },
      uuid: {
        type: Sequelize.CHAR
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Stores');
  }
};
```

Comment: а есть какие-то ошибки и т.п.? тут есть предположение, что очередность не сохранена,  может после создания таблицы `Stores` сделать так  `queryInterface.createTable(/* создаем таблицу Stores */).then(/* создание страницы Orders с привязкой */)`

Comment: == 20190522143914-create-orders: migrating =======

ERROR: Failed to open the referenced table 'stores', вот ошибка, а как и где расписать очередность можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, судя по комментарию, таблицы `Stores` еще нет, когда создается `Orders`, вижу, что миграция называется `20190522143914-create-orders`, вот временная метка `20190522143914`, посмотрите, у `Stores` метка временная должна быть раньше, чтобы все правильно привязалось.

Либо в одной миграции используйте конструкцию `.then` после создания таблицы `Stores`

Comment: Спасибо!теперь все ок)

Comment: @ЭмильКулуев отлично, можно отметить мой ответ как правильный)